# Best way to handle multiple type of users in Django

Tags: python, django

In my project I have to deal with different type of users e.g. **costumers** and **employers**. Each type of user have its own fields and permissions: costumer can buy things whereas employer can not.

I have read the Django docs and it looks like there are two options:

1. Costumize the `AbstractUser` class and adding **all** the fields of costumers and employers. Then use the **permission system** to grant/revoke permission or create a group for each type of user. The downside here is that there unused fields.
2. Adopt the *proxy model*:

   ```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User
   from django.db import models
   ```

   class Costumer(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   ```
   class Meta:
       db_table = 'costumers'
       permissions = (
           ("access_this", "User may access this"),
       )
       ordering = []
   ```

   class Employee(models.Model):
       user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   ```
   class Meta:
       db_table = 'employers'
       permissions = (
           ("access_that", "User may access that"),
       )
       ordering = []
   ```

   This case seems more reasonable but I don't know how to deal with the permissions. Consider I'd like to use `@permission_required` instead of checking the type (if the user has a specific field) because it seems more legit for Django system.

So in the end, what is the best way to approach such scenario?

Comment: I like the proxy model, from a coding perspective. When you want Costumer data you start with Costumers.some_things_set.filter(...), and from Employee you start with Employee.other_things_set.filter(...). Less prone to errors (mistakenly showing Costumers info to Employees and visa versa), and easier to read the code.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to use permissions in this case i.e. restrict access to the costumer/employer

Comment: two groups, each user belongs to one of them https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is much better.

> The downside here is that there unused fields.

I disagree with this, you don't have to store all the fields within the `User` model. Also, if you're talking about 5 fields for example, that doesn't really matter.

---

You can extend `AbtractUser` and also use some composition; you don't have to put all the fields there:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     email = ...
     ...
     # for the employer, let's say you want to save the company details
     company = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Company', null=True, blank=True)
     ...
     # for the customer
     customer_details = models.ForeignKey('...')
```

This way you could record a `user_type` if you want or deduce the type from the foreign key (if there is a company, it's an employer).

---

To help you more with the model, I need to know what differentiate an employer from a customer in your application. Note that with that solution, an instance of `User` could be both.

---

Concerning the permissions, I feel like it's a separate problem; I'd recommend you to sort it last. If the design you pick is close to the reality and you get the features working; adding custom permissions will be really easy.

Comment: The difference is two fields. In my project they are just relations with other tables. I think I'll use your approach since with the other I don't understand how to handle permissions i.e. checking the user type.

Comment: However, I still think the other approach is more "logical".